Multi-line tooltip, dynamically
Imagine a component has a dynamic tooltip.
It may be quite long. In that case, the user wants it to be split into multiple lines. The end goal is to never cut a tooltip with a screen edge. For example, on screens with low resolution long tooltips may exceed the total screen width.

How can I achieve it?
Remember, the text is dynamic, I can't wrap it in <html></html> and scatter <br> tags here and there.
package demos.text.field;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.Container;

public class TextFieldDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container mainPanel = createMainPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Text field demo");
        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(createTextField());
        return panel;
    }

    private static JTextField createTextField() {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField("Text field with a tooltip");
        textField.setToolTipText("A " + "very ".repeat(10) + "long tooltip that must be split");
        return textField;
    }
}

Java 8.

So what excactly keeps you from inserting some <br> elements? For example, at each 5th space, or after a certain amount of characters?

What is stopping you from counting characters of the final string, adding a  tag at the last white space when it reaches a threshold and resetting counter in a loop?

How about adding a JTextArea with JTextArea#setLineWrap(true) to the JToolTip?
This JTextArea will automatically wrap the text if it exceeds the width set by JTextArea.html#setColumns(...).
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LineWrapToolTipTest {
  private Component makeUI() {
    String very = String.join(" ", Collections.nCopies(10, "very"));
    String txt = "A " + very + " long tooltip that must be line wrap";
    JButton b1 = new JButton("JToolTip(Default)");
    b1.setToolTipText(txt + ": 1");
    JButton b2 = makeButton("LineWrapToolTip short");
    b2.setToolTipText("short: 2");
    JButton b3 = makeButton("LineWrapToolTip long");
    b3.setToolTipText(txt + ": 3");
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.add(b1);
    p.add(b2);
    p.add(b3);
    return p;
  }

  private static JButton makeButton(String title) {
    return new JButton(title) {
      private transient JToolTip tip;

      @Override public JToolTip createToolTip() {
        if (tip == null) {
          tip = new LineWrapToolTip();
          tip.setComponent(this);
        }
        return tip;
      }

      @Override public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) {
        String txt = super.getToolTipText(e);
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() ->
            Optional.ofNullable(SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(tip))
                .filter(w -> w.getType() == Window.Type.POPUP)
                .ifPresent(Window::pack));
        return txt;
      }
    };
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new LineWrapToolTipTest().makeUI());
      frame.setSize(320, 240);
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}

class LineWrapToolTip extends JToolTip {
  private final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(0, 20);
  private final JLabel label = new JLabel(" ");

  protected LineWrapToolTip() {
    super();
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    // textArea.setColumns(20);
    textArea.setOpaque(true);
    LookAndFeel.installColorsAndFont(
        textArea, "ToolTip.background", "ToolTip.foreground", "ToolTip.font");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(textArea);
  }

  @Override public final void setLayout(LayoutManager mgr) {
    super.setLayout(mgr);
  }

  @Override public final Component add(Component comp) {
    return super.add(comp);
  }

  @Override public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    // return getLayout().preferredLayoutSize(this);
    Dimension d = getLayout().preferredLayoutSize(this);
    label.setText(textArea.getText());
    Insets i = getInsets();
    Insets ti = textArea.getInsets();
    Insets tm = textArea.getMargin();
    int pad = i.left + i.right + ti.left + ti.right + tm.left + tm.right;
    d.width = Math.min(d.width, label.getPreferredSize().width + pad);
    return d;
  }

  @Override public void setTipText(String tipText) {
    String oldValue = textArea.getText();
    if (!Objects.equals(oldValue, tipText)) {
      textArea.setText(tipText);
      firePropertyChange("tiptext", oldValue, tipText);
      revalidate();
      repaint();
    }
  }

  @Override public String getTipText() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(textArea).map(JTextArea::getText).orElse(null);
  }
}


It's not trivial to break a String into smaller segments.  Here's one way to do it.

Get a line segment
Find the last space
Add a break after the line segment

The splitText method has two parameters, the String and the width of the line segment.  The width must be a reasonable number so the segment will have a space near the end of the segment.
Here's the output from your example. I split the line into two pieces manually so it would fit in the answer without a scrollbar.
<html>A very very very very very<br>very very very very 
very long<br>tooltip that must be split.</html>

Here's the complete runnable code.
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TextFieldDemo implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TextFieldDemo());
    }
    
    private String toolTipString;
    
    public TextFieldDemo() {
        String text = "A " + "very ".repeat(10) + "long tooltip that must be split.";
        this.toolTipString = splitText(text, 30);
    }
    
    private String splitText(String text, int width) {
        if (text.length() <= width) {
            return "<html>" + text + "</html>"; 
        }
        
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int startIndex = 0;
        int endIndex = width;
        int finalIndex = text.length();

        do {
            String s = text.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
            int tempIndex = s.length() - 1;

            // Find last space
            if (tempIndex >= (width - 1)) {
                tempIndex = s.lastIndexOf(' ');
                tempIndex += startIndex;
            } else {
                tempIndex = finalIndex;
            }
            
            // Append break
            builder.append(text.substring(startIndex, tempIndex));
            if (tempIndex < finalIndex) {
                builder.append("<br>");
            }
            
            // Set next text segment
            startIndex = tempIndex + 1;
            endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + width, finalIndex);
            
        } while (startIndex < finalIndex);
        
        return "<html>" + builder.toString() + "</html>"; 
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Text field demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(100, 100, 100, 100));
        panel.add(createTextField());
        return panel;
    }

    private JTextField createTextField() {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(30);
        textField.setText("Text field with a tooltip");
        textField.setToolTipText(toolTipString);
        return textField;
    }

}


Thank you! Though, it feels way too low-level. I wonder if there's another way

@Cagepi: Hide the splitText method in a different class.  Now it's high-level.
